# update StructuredBuffer in compute shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm writing a compute shader which will be called on each frame in Unity.

There is a very big **RWStructuredBuffer<> buffer**, and it will be used during each computation, However before I use it, some elements in RWStructuredBuffer<> buffer may have been modified since the last frame. So I have to update it before I use it. I found there are 2 possible ways

1. set the latest entire RWStructuredBuffer<> buffer to GPU. (It's not efficiency since this buffer is big)
2. set a **StructuredBuffer<> update**, it only contains elements in **RWStructuredBuffer<> buffer** that has been modified since the last frame. Then update the RWStructuredBuffer<> buffer. (The problem is when we do the updating operation from the main() in compute shader, it will split into many threads, and each thread is doing  overlapping updating operation and will make it even slower.)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know the unity API, but DirectX actually has methods (UpdateSubresource in DX11, CopyBufferRegion in DX12) to copy some **part** of a buffer to a part of another buffer. That way, you only need to upload the updated elements to the GPU, and you can rely on the hardware to handle overlapping or any other possible problem related to multithreading.